# How can I have only one checkbox checked out of two?

Tags: reactjs

I've got two checkboxes and I need to have only one of them true at the time.
So if checkbox1 is true then checkbox2 should be false.
My current code works only when I play around with first checkbox but the second one doesn't behave correctly.

Here are my checkboxes:

```
<Checkbox
 checked={checkbox1}
 onChange={onChange}
/>
<Checkbox
 checked={checkbox2}
 onChange={onChange}
/>
```

My CheckBox component:

```
<input
 type="checkbox"
 className="filled-in"
 checked={this.state.checked}
 data-cy={this.props.cyCheckbox}
/>
```

And my parent component where I am trying to manipulate state to set CheckBox checked true or false:

```
<Access
 checkbox1={this.state.input.checkbox1}
 checkbox2={this.state.input.checkbox2}
 onChange={this.updateInput}
/>;
state = {
  input:{
   checkbox1: false,
   checkbox2: false,
  }
}
updateInput = (key, value) => {
 let { input } = this.state;
 input[key] = value;
 this.setState({ input });
 window.input = input;

 //this is where I try to set another Checkbox false if first one is true.

 if (input.checkbox1) {
 input.checkbox2= false;
 } else if (input.checkbox2) {
 input.checkbox1= false;
 } else {
 input.checkbox2= true;
 input.checkbox1= true;
 } 
}
```

Comment: Checkbox is used for multiple choices, why not radio button. If you need to style it like checkbox, search some css instead.

Comment: The issue is likely in the way that you have integrated your component and checkbox. It will be helpful to post the full definition of the two classes rather than excerpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure because your examples are incomplete, but I think your issue is that your checkbox code can never reach the `else if` clause unless the first checkbox is already unchecked. Make your conditionals based on key and value and you'll be fine. Something like:

```
if (key === 'checkbox1' && value) {
    input.checkbox1 = true;
    input.checkbox2 = false;
} else if (key === 'checkbox2' && value) {
    input.checkbox1 = false;
    input.checkbox2 = true;
}
```